# Determining whether a valid permutation of numbers exists

Tags: algorithm, constraints, permutation

I'm trying to create an algorithm that determines whether a valid permutation of numbers exists, based on a list of rules.

I have `n` nodes and `n` integers, each node contains a list of integers that it cannot be paired with, and my goal is to determine whether or not it is possible to pair each node with an integer.

Currently, my best solution is to attempt to pick a number and node that can be paired, remove them from the lists, and then recursively call my function.

In the worst case this could generate all possible permutations, in factorial time. Is it possible to determine if a valid pairing exists without generating all permutations?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem will be reduce to Maximum Bipartite Matching, and you can use Ford - Fulkerson algorithm to solve it in O(nm) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm.

The idea is you can create a graph with vertices are n integers and n nodes and there will be an directed edge from a node to an integer if you can use that integer to represent that node.
The graph can be divided into two set from when you can apply the above algorithm.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this reduction works? I think you're right, but I cannot +1 based on this answer.

Comment: @Heuster: just edit, to fully understand, you should learn about the Maximum Bipartite Matching, but the basic idea is when you can divide a graph to two set A and B, each vertices in set A doesn't have a direct edge to another vertices in set A, vice versa, we can have an algorithm to match each item from set A to set B. It is similar to the problem of job matching :D

Comment: yes, I understand the reduction. But you also need a source and sink, right? There should be a directed edge from the source to each node, and a directed edge from each integer to the sink. All edges have capacity 1, then, the maximum flow gives a maximum bipartite matching.

Comment: @Heuster you are correct. Actually, there are two algorithms to do it, one is the one that I posted above, another one you dont even need to add source and sink, it is called augmenting path algorithm :D

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more details about how those "lists of integers that cannot be paired with" are generated, no.
The solution for this kind of problems is the Divide and conquer algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of it as an [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

You can assign huge costs for combinations that you do not want to be assigned to and zero cost for all feasible combinations.

Minimize your objective function and if the result is greater than zero, then it means that feasible assignment is not possible.

Standard Hungarian Algorithm can be applied